# MYSQL How can I get the time difference between two rows of data?

Tags: mysql

I have a database that is acting as a timeclock of sorts. Each time an employee times in or out, a new timestamp row is created which logs the employee, the job they are at, whether it is in or out, and the time.

I have it working right now as long as they don't time in or out more than once in a 12 hour period, but how can I improve my code so they can time in and out of multiple jobs in a day?

```html
SELECT
    CONCAT(employees.Fname, ' ', employees.Lname) AS name, 
    timeInData.jobPK, 
    timeInData.timestamp AS TimeIn, 
    timeOutData.timestamp AS TimeOut, 
    timeInData.TSPK,
    timeOutData.TSPK, 
    TIMEDIFF(timeOutData.timestamp, timeInData.timestamp) AS hours,
    ROUND((sec_to_time(TIME_TO_SEC(timeOutData.timestamp) - TIME_TO_SEC(timeInData.timestamp)) /10000 * employees.cost), 2) AS empcost
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM timestamps WHERE status = 1 AND jobPK=$job) AS timeInData
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM timestamps WHERE status = 0 AND jobPK=$job) AS timeOutData ON timeInData.jobPk = timeOutData.jobPk AND timeInData.employeePK = timeOutData.employeePK
    JOIN employees ON timeInData.employeePK = employees.employeePK
WHERE
    timeOutData.timestamp BETWEEN timeInData.timestamp AND date_add(timeInData.timestamp, INTERVAL 720 MINUTE)
ORDER BY
    name ASC, TimeIn ASC;
```

Right now, if there are 4 timestamps in a day, it will take each time in and subtract it by each time out, resulting in way too many rows of data. Are there any solutions to this? Or even just some other articles that can help answer my question. I've scoured the internet with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure SQL solution, I'd try somewhere around these lines:

```
SELECT
    e.*,
    ti.timestamp AS TimeIn,
    to.timestamp AS TimeOut
FROM employees AS e
JOIN timestamps AS to
    ON to.employeePK = e.employeePK
    AND to.jobPK = $job
    AND to.status = 0
JOIN timestamps AS ti
    ON ti.employeePK = e.employeePK
    AND ti.jobPK = $job
    AND ti.timestamp = (
        SELECT MAX(ts.timestamp)
        FROM timestamps AS ts
        WHERE ts.employeePK = e.employeePK
        AND ts.jobPK = $job
        AND ts.status = 1
    )
    AND ti.status = 1
```

But in my opinion dealing with time sequences like this doesn't really belong to relational algebra. I'd rather go with a stored procedure creating a cursor (iterating over employees) and a temporary table (to contain running sums). Or even take out all the calculation to the programming language with the same idea. Having an employeePK, it is easy to select all entries within last 12 hours and process them on the programming language's side.